# C - saving one file to two separate arrays and printing each element

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I have a file of DNA sequences and an associated IDs and I'm trying to save the even lines (the IDs) to one array and the odd lines (the sequences) to another. Then I want to compare all of the sequences with each other to find the unique sequences. For example is Seq A is AGTCGAT and Seq B is TCG, Seq B is not unique. I want to save the unique sequences and their IDs to an output file and id the sequences are not unique, only save the ID to the output file and print "Deleting sequence with ID: " to the console. I'm pretty much done but Im running into a few problems. I tried printing out the two separate arrays, sequences[] and headers[], but for some reason, they only contain two out of the 5 strings (the file has 5 IDs and 5 headers). And then the information isn't printing out to the screen the way it's supposed to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  int total_seq = 20000;
  char seq[900];
  char** headers;
  char** sequences;
  int sequence_size = 0;

  headers = malloc(total_seq * sizeof(char*));
  sequences = malloc(total_seq * sizeof(char*));

  int index;
  for(index = 0; index < total_seq; index++){
    headers[index] = malloc(900 * sizeof(char));
    sequences[index] = malloc(900 * sizeof(char));
  }

  FILE *dna_file;
  FILE *new_file;
  dna_file = fopen("inabc.fasta", "r");
  new_file = fopen("output.fasta", "w");

  if (dna_file == NULL){
    printf("Error");
    return 0;
  }

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  while(fgets(seq, sizeof seq, dna_file)){
    if(i%2 == 0){
      strcpy(headers[i/2], seq);
      i++;
    }
    else{
      strcpy(sequences[i/2], seq);
      i++;
    }
  }


  fclose(dna_file);
  sequence_size = i/2;

  char* result;
  for(i=0; i < sequence_size; i++){
    for(j=0; j < sequence_size; j++){
      if(i==j){
        continue;
    }
      result = strstr(sequences[j], sequences[i]);
      if(result== NULL){
        fprintf(new_file,"%s", headers[i]);
        fprintf(new_file,"%s", sequences[i]);
      }
      else{
        printf("Deleting sequence with id: %s \n", headers[i]);
        printf(sequences[i]);
        fprintf(new_file,"%s", headers[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

The sample file inabc.fasta is short but the actual file I'm working with is very long, which is why I've used malloc. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The sample input file inabc.fasta:

```
cat inabc.fasta

> id1 header1
abcd
> id2 header2
deghj
> id3 header3
defghijkabcd
> id4 header4
abcd
> id5 header5
xcvbnnmlll
```

So for this sample, sequences 1 and 4 will not be saved to the output file

Comment: if you delete all the duplicates you'll lose both copies of the duplicate.

Comment: well I'm not actually deleting anything. If the sequence is a subset of another sequence, I'm just not adding that sequence to the output file. I tried to put a few printf statements right after I saved the strings to the two arrays and it seems like the arrays don't contain everything I want them to contain but I'm not sure why

Comment: If you will edit and post a snippet of your data that contains at least one unique and several non-unique ID's & sequences, then it will make debugging much easier and valid.

Comment: this line: printf(sequences[i]); does not compile

Comment: there are a few lines missing from the end of the posted file.  1) fclose(new_file); 2) return(0);  3) the final '}'

Comment: both files are being fopen() before checking of any fopen failed.  then no (possibly open file) is being closed before the call to exit()

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
while( fgets(seq, sizeof seq, dna_file) ) {
    if( i % 2 == 0 ){
        strcpy(headers[i], seq);
        i++;
    }
    else {
        strcpy(sequences[i-1], seq);
        i++;
    }
}
```

is going to skip every other element in your arrays:

1. When `i == 0`, it'll store in `headers[0]`
2. When `i == 1`, it'll store in `sequences[0]`
3. When `i == 2`, it'll store in `headers[2]`
4. When `i == 3`, it'll store in `sequences[2]`

and so on.

Then you do:

```
sequence_size = i/2;
```

so if you loop `sequence_size` times, you'll only make it half way through the piece of the array you've written to, and every other element you print will be uninitialized. This is why you're only printing half the elements (if you have 5 elements, then `i / 2 == 2`, and you'll only see 2), and why it "isn't printing out to the screen the way it's supposed to".

You'll be better off just using either two separate counters when you read in your input, and a separate variable to store whether you're on an odd or even line of input.

For instance:

```
int i = 0, j = 0, even = 1;
while( fgets(seq, sizeof seq, dna_file) ) {
    if( even ){
        strcpy(headers[i++], seq);
        even = 0;
    }
    else {
        strcpy(sequences[j++], seq);
        even = 1;
    }
}
```

Here it's better to have two variables, since if you read in an odd number of lines, your two arrays will contain different numbers of read elements.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments, there are a few logic errors in your output routine you need to correct. Below, I have left your code **in comments**, so you can follow the changes and additions made.

There are several ways you can approach memory management a bit more efficiently, and provide a way to cleanly iterate over your data without tracking counters throughout your code. Specifically, when you allocate your array of `pointers-to-pointer-to-char`, use `calloc` instead of `malloc` so that your pointers are initialized to `zero/NULL`. This allows you to easily iterate over only those pointers that have been assigned.

There is no need to allocate `20000` `900` char arrays (`times 2`) before reading your data. Allocate your pointers (or start with a smaller number of pointers say `256` and `realloc` as needed), then simply allocate for each element in `headers` and `sequences` **as needed** within your read loop. Further, instead of allocating `1800` chars (`900 * 2`) every time you add an element to `headers` and `sequences`, just allocate the memory required to hold the data. This can make a **huge** difference. For example, you allocate `20000 * 900 * 2 = 36000000 bytes (36M)` before you start reading this small set of sample data. Even allocating all `20000` pointers, allocating memory as needed for this sample data, limits memory usage to `321,246 bytes` (less that `1%` of `36M`)

The logic in your write loop will not work. You must move your write of the data **outside of the inner loop**. Otherwise you have no way of testing whether to **Delete** a duplicate entry. Further testing `result` does not provide a way to skip duplicates. `result` changes with every iteration of the inner loop. You need to both **test** and set a **flag** that will control whether or not to delete the duplicate once you leave the inner loop.

Finally, since you are allocating memory dynamically, you are responsible for tracking the memory allocated and freeing the memory when no longer needed. Allocating your array of pointers with `calloc` makes freeing the memory in use a snap.

Take a look at the changes and additions I'm made to your code. Understand the changes and let me know if you have any questions. **Note:** there are many checks omitted for sake of not cluttering the code. You should at minimum make sure you do not exceed the `20000` pointers allocated when run on a full dataset, and `realloc` as needed. You should also check that `strdup` succeeded (it's allocating memory), although you get some assurance comparing the `headers` and `sequences` index count. I'm sure there are many more that make sense. Good luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSEQ 20000
#define SZSEQ 900

int main ()
{

    int total_seq = MAXSEQ;     /* initialize all variables */
    char seq[SZSEQ] = {0};
    char **headers = NULL;      /* traditionally variables  */
    char **sequences = NULL;    /* declared at beginning    */
    // char *result = NULL;
    // int sequence_size = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    int hidx = 0;
    int sidx = 0;
    // int idx = 0;      /* (see alternative in fgets loop) */
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int del = 0;

    /* calloc initilizes to 0 & allows iteration on addresses */
    headers = calloc (total_seq, sizeof (*headers));
    sequences = calloc (total_seq, sizeof (*sequences));

    /* allocate as needed if possible - see read loop  */
//     for (index = 0; index < total_seq; index++) {
//         headers[index] = malloc (900 * sizeof (char));
//         sequences[index] = malloc (900 * sizeof (char));
//     }

    FILE *dna_file = NULL;
    FILE *new_file = NULL;
    dna_file = fopen ("inabc.fasta", "r");
    new_file = fopen ("output.fasta", "w+");    /* create if not existing "w+"  */

    if (!dna_file || !new_file) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: file open failed.\n");
        return 1;                               /* 1 indicates error condition  */
    }

    while (fgets (seq, sizeof (seq), dna_file)) /* read dna_file & separate     */
    {
        len = strlen (seq);                     /* strip newline from seq end   */
        if (seq[len-1] == '\n')                 /* it's never good to leave \n  */
            seq[--len] = 0;                     /* scattered through your data  */

        /* if header line has '>' as first char -- use it!  */
        if (*seq == '>')
            headers[hidx++] = strdup (seq);     /* strdup allocates             */
        else
            sequences[sidx++] = strdup (seq);

        /* alternative using counter if no '>'  */
//         if (idx % 2 == 0)
//             headers[hidx++] = strdup (seq);
//         else
//             sequences[sidx++] = strdup (seq);
//         idx++
    }

    fclose (dna_file);

    if (hidx != sidx)
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: hidx:sidx (%d:%d) differ.\n", hidx, sidx);

//     sequence_size = (hidx>sidx) ? sidx : hidx;  /* protect against unequal read */
//     
//     for (i = 0; i < sequence_size; i++) {
//         for (j = 0; i < sequence_size; i++) {
//             if (i == j) {
//                 continue;
//             }
//             result = strstr (sequences[j], sequences[i]);
//             if (result == NULL) {
//                 fprintf (new_file, "%s", headers[i]);
//                 fprintf (new_file, "%s", sequences[i]);
//             } else {
//                 printf ("Deleting sequence with id: %s \n", headers[i]);
//                 printf (sequences[i]);
//                 fprintf (new_file, "%s", headers[i]);
//             }
//         }
//     }

    /* by using calloc, all pointers except those assigned are NULL */
    while (sequences[i])    /* testing while (sequences[i] != NULL) */
    {
        j = 0;
        del = 0;
        while (sequences[j])
        {
            if (i == j)
            {
                j++;
                continue;
            }

            if (strstr (sequences[j], sequences[i]))    /* set delete flag  */
            {
                del = 1;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }

        if (del) {
            printf ("Deleting id: '%s' with seq: '%s' \n", headers[i], sequences[i]);
            // printf (sequences[i]);
            fprintf (new_file, "%s\n", headers[i]);
        } else {
            fprintf (new_file, "%s\n", headers[i]);
            fprintf (new_file, "%s\n", sequences[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }

    fclose (new_file);

    /* free allocated memory - same simple iteration */
    i = 0;
    while (headers[i])
        free (headers[i++]);      /* free strings allocated by strdup */
    if (headers) free (headers);  /* free the array of pointers       */

    i = 0;
    while (sequences[i])
        free (sequences[i++]);
    if (sequences) free (sequences);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/dnaio
Deleting id: '> id1 header1' with seq: 'abcd'
Deleting id: '> id4 header4' with seq: 'abcd'
```

**output.fasta:**

```
$ cat output.fasta
> id1 header1
> id2 header2
deghj
> id3 header3
defghijkabcd
> id4 header4
> id5 header5
xcvbnnmlll
```

**memory allocation/free verification:**

```
==21608== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21608==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21608==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 14 frees, 321,246 bytes allocated
==21608==
==21608== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```